# equivalent to "safely remove hardware" in Windows

Tags: drive, eject

I had always guessed that hitting the eject button in a file manager would be the equivalent of the Windows "safely remove hardware" function for drives. However I notice that hitting eject for drives in Ubuntu does not actually stop the hard drives from spinning, but in Windows the function causes the drive to come to a complete stop. Is there something else I should be doing before removing drives in Ubuntu? Or is the eject function the correct method for Ubuntu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MATE at least it seems clicking the eject button just unmounts the device. To unmount and power off the drive on the command line, you can use `udisksctl`

First list the drives with `lsblk`

```
NAME         MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sdb            8:0    1 15.2G  0 disk 
└─sdb1         8:1    1 15.2G  0 part /media/zanna/4C45-110F
mmcblk0rpmb  179:24   0    4M  0 disk 
mmcblk0boot0 179:8    0    4M  1 disk 
mmcblk0boot1 179:16   0    4M  1 disk 
mmcblk0      179:0    0 29.1G  0 disk 
├─mmcblk0p1  179:1    0  512M  0 part /boot/efi
├─mmcblk0p2  179:2    0 26.7G  0 part /
└─mmcblk0p3  179:3    0    2G  0 part [SWAP]
```

I want to remove the drive `/dev/sdb` so I would do

```
udisksctl unmount -b /dev/sdb1
udisksctl power-off -b /dev/sdb
```