# How can I safely remove an external disk using the launcher icon?

Tags: launcher, usb-drive, umount

The following animation demonstrates how I tried to safely remove an external USB 2.0 hard disk. However, each time I click on safely remove, the disk is being mounted again.

**Animation:**

[image: GIF animation]

**I can, however, unmount the disk as follows:**

[image: Unmount through Nautilus]

Comment: The CLI way of doing this is at http://askubuntu.com/questions/825577/equivalent-to-safely-remove-hardware-in-windows/825616#825616.

Comment: May i know how did u create this image?

Comment: Thank you @edwinksl! However, I would prefer if the launcher icon was to do what it should.

Comment: @sardapv First, I record a screencast using [Vokoscreen](https://github.com/vkohaupt/vokoscreen). Second, I use [gifenc](https://github.com/orschiro/bin/blob/master/gifenc) to convert the `.mkv` file to `.gif`.

Comment: thanx @orschiro i will try that

Comment: very interesting issue. I'd assume this is a bug in either file manager or Unity. Perhaps there's something that's currently using stuff on the disk so the disk is prevented from unmounting. Test this with USB stick or external hard drive. I'm pretty sure that use of that disk by some process is the cause of this issue. As edwinksl suggested, also test this in command line, you probably will see an error if there's something using the disk. `lsof` can help im determining what is doing that

Comment: @Serg please see my edited question.

Answer (score 0):

Linux Mint often won't release an external USB drive either. Mint is based on Ubuntu. To protect the external drive data I quit all applications and shut down. The USB hookup cable also has an on-off switch which is convenient.

Comment: That we can safely remove a USB-device after shutdown is trivial and doesn't offer a solution for the issue..,